# SSIS Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection with the following error message: "Could not create a managed connection

Tags: ssis, microsoft-dynamics, kingswaysoft

I am getting this error when trying to connect Dynamics CDS.

[ADO NET Source [2]] Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {6F23C652-54D5-487B-AF3D-3354FD263841} with the following error message: "Could not create a managed connection manager.".

I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Can someone assists?

Sorry Forgot to mention.. Yes,, I am using KingswaySoft CDS Tool. –

I tried reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 and SQL Data Tools as well. But nothing is solving the issue.

Comment: Sorry Forgot to mention.. Yes,, I am using KingswaySoft CDS Tool. I have checked with Premioud ADO.Net Source as well.. Getting the same error.

Comment: Is this a new problem or has this worked in the past? Normally there is a lot more detail in the error message that gives you a clue to the issue (i.e. can't log in)

Comment: That is the only message I am getting. Check below the full message.

[Premium ADO NET Source [2]] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Could not create a managed connection manager.".
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Premium ADO NET Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Comment: Is this a new problem or has this been working in the past? I'm trying to understand whether you have ever successfully connected to CDS

Comment: I am able to connect to the CDS and can preview the data but whenever I try to execute the task, it fails.

Comment: It fails when you execute the task in Visual Studio?